# Automatically add Google Analytics tracking code to SFMC Cloud Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, google-analytics

Is there a way to automatically add Google Analytics tracking code to Cloud Pages?

The objective is to have the code already implemented on every new Landing Page created.

Comment: You could probably write some clientside JS to append the URLs with the right analytics parameters and reuse it on each page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to automatically add Google Analytics tracking code to every new Cloud Page created. You can, however,

1. Create a [Code Snippet](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_create_code_snippet.htm&type=5) that contains the Google Analytics tracking code
2. Use the [ContentBlockByName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyname.htm) AMPscript function (or [ContentBlockByKey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbykey.htm), [ContentBlockById](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyid.htm)) to insert the tracking code into the CloudPage